# What data structure would be best for a code cross referencer?

Tags: algorithms, python, abstract-data-types

I want to write a JavaScript cross referencer (*in Python*) that will build a cross-reference of JavaScript functions for a given input file. I am trying to think of what Abstract Data Type would work well for this to represent the call tree.

I am thinking of using a General Tree (*a tree that has a root node with many branches*).

Given that a function may be called by many other functions (i.e. there is not a 1-1 relationship between parent nodes and child nodes), I am not sure what ADT would work best for this.

Any pointers on what ADT would make sense are appreciated.

<

Comment: An abstract data type is determined by the operations performed on it. The choice of data structure is usually determined by which operations need to be efficient. Finally, "call tree" is a less common term than "call graph" seeing as recursion is a thing.

Comment: Yes it looks like a call-graph is what I want.